# Espresso, test launch of second activity

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I would like to know how to test the launch of an activity on the click of a button. I'm aware that this could possibly be made with this: 
`onView(withText(R.string.button_next_activity)).perform(click());`, then `onView(withId(R.id.second_tv_welcome)).check(matches(withText(R.string.second_tv_welcome)));` where `second_tv_welcome` is a textView from the second activity. But my current activity is starting the facebook web view, I don't know what are the ids in this activity, plus I don't find this method of checking (checking if a textview exist and has the expected text) very clean.
Any workaround for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using external services in functional tests. This includes making API calls, using GPS and things that do that internally, e.g. Facebook or Google+ login button.

The way I go with it, is by creating two flavors and putting login button layout in each: one real, for production and one mock, which doesn't do anything except for notifying that login action succeeded (or failed), so the calling code may go to another Activity. This might sound hard to do properly at first, so you may want to have a look at the relevant code of my pet app:

- [Facebook login button code](https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/tree/develop/app/src/main/java/com/vielengames/ui/login)
- [Facebook login button layout](https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/blob/develop/app/src/main/res/layout/login_button_facebook.xml)
- [stub login button code and layout](https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/tree/develop/app/src/stub_login)

Two flavors in this app define stub_login folder as src/res folders in [build.gradle](https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/blob/develop/app/build.gradle):

```
sourceSets {
    mock {
        java { srcDir 'src/stub_login/java' }
        res { srcDir 'src/stub_login/res' }
    }
    apiary {
        java { srcDir 'src/stub_login/java' }
        res { srcDir 'src/stub_login/res' }
    }
}
```

And [tests](https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/blob/develop/app/src/androidTestMock/java/com/vielengames/ui/NotLoggedOnTestCase.java) (not too many of them for now) are run with:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTestMockDebug
```

Note that functional tests are in `src/androidTestMock` and unit tests may stay in `src/androidTest`.

Comment: Even if it doesn't answer my question your resources are very precious. I'll take example on what you did and adapt it to my project. Thanks a lot! NB: I do my unit testing with robolectric+mockito

Comment: @E-Kami If this doesn't answer you, then I probably did not understand the question. Does your `button_next_activity`'s click handler call `startActivity` directly or is it a Facebook login button?

Comment: yes the click on a button call `startActivity`, and what I asked was to test if the proper activity was launched (because in some cases I don't want the facebook login to be launched but another activity). Anyway what you gave me is very useful. I'm integrating it to my project atm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @E-Kami I'm testing that an Activity is started by checking if some `onView withId(R.id.exists_only_on_this_activity) check matches(isDisplayed())` and wrapping that in a helper method called `checkOnSomeActivity`. But it usually makes no sense to assert that specific thing.